# Intellij Error while starting: Java: jobScheduler FJ pool

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I could not find anything on the internet which talks about my topic. I have absolutely no idea were the problem is and what causes this crash.
I used Intellij the other day ago and now it just isn't working anymore.

I am going to put the entire crash log in order for you experts to check.

Interesting fact is that I run the Apple Silicon version (on a 2020 Mac Mini M1) which does not work. Just for interest I tried the intel version which worked, even though it was really slow.

I tried to restart my system, reinstall the app and some other ideas on similar problems which didn't bring me to a solution.

My system is a M1 2020 Mac mini on the newest Big Sur Beta version.

Crash Log:
https://github.com/DrSquidyShity/intellij-crash-log/blob/b2104c6b179dd894bc52004bcb0da8bd571aa635/crash-log.txt

Regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

See the [bug on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-3715) (mac os 12 beta6 Unable to start IDEA)

As a workaround, add the following [VM options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869):

```
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
```